# How can prove that

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ is a non-square matrix, and $B$ is a square matrix.
Is it true that if $AB=A$ then $B=I$ ?

If it is not true in general, is there special cases to make this statement true?

Comment: What happens if $A=0$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What do you think is the answer?

Answer (score 5):

It's false.

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1&
0
\end{bmatrix}\\
B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

As for special cases, if there's a matrix $M$ with $MA = I$, then it's true; that amounts to saying that the number $n$ of rows of $A$ is larger than or equal to the number $k$ of columns, but that those $k$ columns are in fact linearly independent.

Comment: More succinctly, $A$ must have full "column-rank" (or we can say that $A$ "has a trivial nullspace").

Comment: Right; I wasn't certain OP knew either of those terms yet, but it's nice to introduce them.

Answer (score 4):

$$AB = A \implies AB - A = \mathbf{0} \implies A(B - I) = \mathbf{0}$$

Hence two obvious solutions are $A = \mathbf{0}$ or $B = I$. However, it is also possible that a product of two non-zero matrices is zero.